# Background not covering whole display screen?

Tags: html, css

I am having trouble with my background covering the whole page vertically, as it is only halfway now. This is what I am currently doing, and I am not sure why it is not working.

```
<div class="bg">
  <div class="container">
    some more code here
  </div>
</div>
```

And in my CSS I have:

```
body, html {
 height: 100%;
}

.bg {
 background-image:url(myimage.png);
 background-height: 100%;
 background-position: center;
 background-repeat: no-repeat;
 background-size: cover;
}
```

I have also tried a few solutions from previous posts on here to no avail.

Thank you for your time.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your `bg` class will need a `height` value, otherwise it will only be as tall as the content that fills it.

Also, `background-height` is not a valid property.

```
body, html {
 height: 100%;
}

.bg {
 height: 100%;
 background-image:url(http://www.fillmurray.com/800/400);
 background-position: center;
 background-repeat: no-repeat;
 background-size: cover;
}
```

Change the image to your image and you should be good. See the attached fiddle.

https://fiddle.jshell.net/krqvhymn/

Your can also give your `container` class a `height` value. Depends on what you are looking to do

Answer (score 1):

Unfortunately I can't comment, so I'm offering this answer as further help (although it doesn't answer your question):

You can take those background properties and use shorthand to place them all into one line, instead of separates. That would look like:

```
.bg {
   height: 100%;
   background: url(myimage.png) no repeat cover center;
   }
```